# Why does Delphi TOpenDialog fail to open in the Initial Directory?

Tags: delphi, topendialog

I am using `TOpenDialog` (in Delphi 10.4) to show the user the PDF files I have installed for them in their Documents folder. In that folder, I have created a folder `MyFolder10.2` and copied the PDF files there.

The code is simple and has worked in the past, and even now it still works on my older slower Win10 machine. But on my newer faster Win10 computer, it only works SOME of the time. When it does not work, a file dialog is opened but in some other directory (not sure where that comes from), and it does not filter the file type (`.pdf`) that was set in the `TOpenDialog` component.

Any way to track down this mystery?

```
docPath:= GetEnvironmentVariable('USERPROFILE') + '\Documents\MyFolder10.2\';
OpenDocsDlg.InitialDir := docPath;
OpenDocsDlg.Execute;
```

Comment: The *correct* way to get the path to the user's `Documents` folder is to use `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS)` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents)` instead. Not that doing so will change the dialog's behavior, but you should still do the right thing nonetheless.  Microsoft could always move/rename the default folder path in the future (they've done it before), or the user could have customized it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prior to Vista, `TOpenDialog` is a wrapper for the [`GetOpenFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamew) API, where `TOpenDialog.InitialDir` maps to the `OPENFILENAME.lpstrInitialDir` field.

On Vista and later, `TOpenDialog` (usually, depending on configuration) wraps the [`IFileDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog)/[`IFileOpenDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileopendialog) API instead, where `TOpenDialog.InitialDir` maps to the [`IFileDialog.SetFolder()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog-setfolder) method (not to [`IFolderDialog.SetDefaultFolder()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog-setdefaultfolder), as one would expect).

Per the [`OPENFILENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-openfilenamew) documentation:

> `lpstrInitialDir`
>
> Type: `LPCTSTR`
>
> The initial directory. **The algorithm for selecting the initial directory varies on different platforms.**
>
> Windows 7:
>
> 1. If `lpstrInitialDir` [`TOpenDialog.InitialDir`] has the same value as was passed the first time the application used an Open or Save As dialog box, the path most recently selected by the user is used as the initial directory.
> 2. Otherwise, if `lpstrFile` [`TOpenDialog.FileName`] contains a path, that path is the initial directory.
> 3. Otherwise, if `lpstrInitialDir` is not NULL [`TOpenDialog.InitialDir` is not empty], it specifies the initial directory.
> 4. If `lpstrInitialDir` is NULL [`TOpenDialog.InitialDir` is empty] and the current directory contains any files of the specified filter types, the initial directory is the current directory.
> 5. Otherwise, the initial directory is the personal files directory of the current user.
> 6. Otherwise, the initial directory is the Desktop folder.
>
> Windows 2000/XP/Vista:
>
> 1. If `lpstrFile` [`TOpenDialog.FileName`] contains a path, that path is the initial directory.
> 2. Otherwise, `lpstrInitialDir` [`TOpenDialog.InitialDir`] specifies the initial directory.
> 3. Otherwise, if the application has used an Open or Save As dialog box in the past, the path most recently used is selected as the initial directory. However, if an application is not run for a long time, its saved selected path is discarded.
> 4. If `lpstrInitialDir` is NULL [`TOpenDialog.InitialDir` is empty] and the current directory contains any files of the specified filter types, the initial directory is the current directory.
> 5. Otherwise, the initial directory is the personal files directory of the current user.
> 6. Otherwise, the initial directory is the Desktop folder.

And per the [Common Item Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/common-file-dialog#controlling-the-default-folder) documentation:

> ### Controlling the Default Folder
>
> Almost any folder in the Shell namespace can be used as the default folder for the dialog (the folder presented when the user chooses to open or save a file). Call `IFileDialog::SetDefaultFolder` prior to calling `Show` [`TOpenDialog.Execute()`] to do so.
>
> **The default folder is the folder in which the dialog starts the first time a user opens it from your application. After that, the dialog will open in the last folder a user opened or the last folder they used to save an item.** See [State Persistence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/common-file-dialog#state-persistence) for more details.
>
> **You can force the dialog to always show the same folder when it opens, regardless of previous user action, by calling `IFileDialog::SetFolder` [`TOpenDialog.InitialDir`]**. However, we do not recommended doing this. If you call `SetFolder` before you display the dialog box, the most recent location that the user saved to or opened from is not shown. Unless there is a very specific reason for this behavior, it is not a good or expected user experience and should be avoided. In almost all instances, `IFileDialog::SetDefaultFolder` is the better method.
>
> When saving a document for the first time in the Save dialog, you should follow the same guidelines in determining the initial folder as you did in the Open dialog. If the user is editing a previously existing document, open the dialog in the folder where that document is stored, and populate the edit box with that document's name. Call `IFileSaveDialog::SetSaveAsItem()` with the current item prior to calling `Show` [`TOpenDialog.Execute()`].

Neither `TOpenDialog` nor [`TFileOpenDialog`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TFileOpenDialog) have properties that map to the `IFileDialog.SetDefaultFolder()` or `IFileDialog.SetSaveAsItem()` methods. However, the [`TFileOpenDialog.Dialog`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TCustomFileDialog.Dialog) property does give you access to the underlying `IFileDialog`, so you can manually call these methods, such as in the `TFileOpenDialog.OnExecute` event.

Comment: Very interesting information, but alas the mystery is not solved. First of all the returned path with my original code was always correct as I confirmed by showing it in a dialog just before executing my OpenDocsDlg. More testing reveled that the dialog returned was used in the TOpenDlg only when the program exe was run from within my programming directory. But failed when run outside that. Following the suggestion about using the TFileopenDialog vs. TOpenDialog, I could not discover how to access

Comment: Finishing my comment. Sorry. I could not figure out syntax to use TFileOpenDialog to "manually call SetFolder" (no example??) - BUT had success getting the called for directory with "FileOpenDocsDlg.DefaultFolder:= docPath;".

Comment: @ScottStalheim I re-checked the `TFileOpenDialog` source, and its `DefaultFolder` property actually calls `IFileDialog.SetFolder()`, not `IFileDialog.SetDefaultFolder()`. I have updated my answer accordingly. Which means, if the `TOpenDialog.InitialDir` does not exist or can't be accessed, `IFileDialog.SetFolder()` gets skipped, and so the dialog's initial directory is determined according to the other rules I outlined.

Comment: Thanks. The key for my understanding is as you said "if the TOpenDialog.InitialDir does not exist or can't be accessed, IFileDialog.SetFolder() gets skipped, and so the dialog's initial directory is determined according to the other rules I outlined.".  Why the folder that I know exists could not be accessed in this one instance is still a mystery, but now I understand why when "something" (?) was changed on the Windows side, it now works fine in either TOpenDialog or TFieDialog.

Answer (score 0):

The detailed answer by @Remy Lebeau triggered me to try again to fix a problematic common scenario I've not managed to fix before, despite numerous attempts:
I have an image edit VCL application with a TFileOpenDialog and a TFileSaveDialog that is often used for editing a bunch of screenshots one by one on a connected Android device which are saved on a desktop computer.
The problem was that the DefaultFolder for the FileOpenDialog didn't stick to the opened Android folder after a save on the computer. That is now fixed to my liking, and the solution might be of interest to someone who needs to play around with the dialogs.

The test code:

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Winapi.ShlObj, Winapi.KnownFolders, Winapi.ActiveX;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    FileOpenDialog1: TFileOpenDialog;
    FileSaveDialog1: TFileSaveDialog;
    OpenButton: TButton;
    SaveButton: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FileOpenDialog1Execute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FileSaveDialog1Execute(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure OpenButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SaveButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FOpenShellItem: IShellItem;
    FSaveShellItem: IShellItem;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function GetItemName(ShellItem: IShellItem; const Flags: Cardinal): string;
var
  pszItemName: LPCWSTR;
begin
  Result := '';
  if ShellItem.GetDisplayName(Flags, pszItemName) = S_OK then
  begin
    Result := pszItemName;
    CoTaskMemFree(pszItemName);
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  pch: PChar;
begin
  DesktopFont := True;

  if SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Pictures, 0, 0, pch) = S_OK then
  begin
    FileOpenDialog1.DefaultFolder := pch;
    FileSaveDialog1.DefaultFolder := pch;
    CoTaskMemFree(pch);
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.OpenButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ShellItem: IShellItem;
  ParentItem: IShellItem;
begin
  if FileOpenDialog1.Execute(Handle) then
  begin
    if fdoAllowMultiSelect in FileOpenDialog1.Options then
      FileOpenDialog1.ShellItems.GetItemAt(0, ShellItem)
    else
      ShellItem := FileOpenDialog1.ShellItem;
    if ShellItem.GetParent(ParentItem) = S_OK then
      FOpenShellItem := ParentItem;


    Memo1.Lines.Add('Opened');
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ItemParsingName:   ' +
      GetItemName(ShellItem, SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING));
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ItemNormalName:   ' +
      GetItemName(ShellItem, SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY));
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ParentItemParsingName:   ' +
      GetItemName(ParentItem, SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING));
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ParentItemNormalame:   ' +
      GetItemName(ParentItem, SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY));
    Memo1.Lines.Add('----------');
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.SaveButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ParentItem: IShellItem;
begin
  if FileSaveDialog1.Execute(Handle) then
  begin
    if FileSaveDialog1.ShellItem.GetParent(ParentItem) = S_OK then
      FSaveShellItem := FileSaveDialog1.ShellItem;


    Memo1.Lines.Add('Saved');
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ItemParsingName:   ' +
      GetItemName(FileSaveDialog1.ShellItem, SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING));
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ItemNormalName:   ' +
      GetItemName(FileSaveDialog1.ShellItem, SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY));
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ParentItemParsingName:   ' +
      GetItemName(ParentItem, SIGDN_DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING));
    Memo1.Lines.Add('ParentItemNormalName:   ' +
      GetItemName(ParentItem, SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY));
    Memo1.Lines.Add('----------');
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FileOpenDialog1Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FOpenShellItem) then
    FileOpenDialog1.Dialog.SetFolder(FOpenShellItem);
end;

procedure TMainForm.FileSaveDialog1Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Note the IFileSaveDialog typecast
  if Assigned(FSaveShellItem) then
    IFileSaveDialog(FileSaveDialog1.Dialog).SetSaveAsItem(FSaveShellItem);
end;

end.
```